# xclip gtk copy file

Tags: gtk, xclip

While trying to copy files into the clipboard through bash, I ran into a bit of trouble.
I'm currently using 'xclip -i -selection clipboard -t text/uri-list <<< $1' .
The script works as expected in QT apps, but gtk doesn't seem to recognize the files/folders copied.

Am I using the wrong mimetype ('text/uri-list'), or should the files not be in the format "file://path/to/file.extension" or is it something else?

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to copy files into gtk filemanagers, by using this script:
`echo -e "copy\n$1\0" | xclip -i -selection clipboard -t x-special/gnome-copied-files`. 
But now I have a problem that they won't copy into qt filemanagers. How do I manage to copy to both?

Comment: After looking into it, It appears that I need to set multiple targets, such as `text/plain`, `text/uri-list` and `x-special/gnome-copied-files` with separate data, but it doesn't appear to be possible. Is there some alternative tool that can do it or could it be done directly within gnome shell extensions?

Comment: Specifying multiple targets is currently not possible in `xclip`: https://github.com/astrand/xclip/issues/32